# how sum two tensors with difference shapes_pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors with these shapes:

```
a_tensor : torch.Size([64, 37])
b_tensor : torch.Size([64, 300])
```

how can I sum them (a_tensor+b_tensor ) and pad a_tensor with zeros to be size of [64,300]?

For example, `a_tensor is [[1 , 2 , 3],[3 , 2 , 1]]` with shape of ([2 , 3])
and
b_ensor is `[[10 , 20 , 30 , 40] , [40 , 30 , 20 , 10]]` with the shape of ([2,4]).

a_tensor + b_tensor would be like this:

```
[[1,2,3,0],[3,2,1,0]] + [[10,20,30,40],[40,30,20,10]] = [[11,22,33,40],[43,32,21,10]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using [`nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html):

```
>>> a = torch.rand(64, 37)
>>> b = torch.rand(64, 300)
```

Measure the padding amount:

```
>>> r = b.size(-1) - a.size(-1)
```

Pad and sum:

```
>>> tf.pad(a, (0,0,r,0)) + b
```

Comment: tf.pad(a, (0,0,r,0)) is the size of (327,37) not (64, 300), The correct one is:
tf.pad(a, (0,r,0,0)).

Comment: Not sure what you were looking for but you asked in your question for `a_tensor` to be padded to a shape of ` [64,300]`...

Comment: It's ok. I changed it according to my purpose. Thanks.